# Prevent wireless router from removing original source MAC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a TP-Link AC5400 Wireless Router and I am currently using it as a WiFi Access Point.

I am trying to collect packets at one client which is constantly pinged by another client in the wireless network. However, all the incoming packets have the source MAC-Adress of the router, not of the acutal client that sent the ping request.

Does this mean the Access Point replaces the source MAC with its own? If so - how can I change that?

Comment: Are you sure you're using/reading the correct field? Wi-Fi uses three MAC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

All routers "replace" the MAC address; that's what routers do. They strip away the original L2 header, handle the packet by its L3 header, then add a new L2 header for the outbound interface (which might be a completely different L2 link type, e.g. from Ethernet to LTE).

On the other hand, Wi-Fi access points *don't* replace the MAC address; they are "bridges" which forward the same L2 frames from one side to the other.

Not all routers are access points and not all access points are routers.

> how can I change that?

Make the AC5400 no longer be a router. Switch it to "bridge" mode – either by selecting an actual mode in the router's settings, or by connecting it through the existing "LAN" bridge that it has and no longer using the "WAN" port for anything.

Comment: The way I read the question, no routing is involved.

Comment: @user1686 The AC5400 doesn't have a bridge mode unfortunately. I just want to communicate between two devices wirelessly, basically the same way as if they were connected to a switch via Ethernet and keep the layer 2.

Comment: Yeah, then you'll have to use the existing L2 bridge that's called the "LAN ports". It's a 4-port switch that's bridged to the Wi-Fi. Don't use the "WAN" port, disable unnecessary DHCP, and you'll have an access point.

Comment: @user1686 Could you please elaborate? I don't understand how to connect a switch to a WiFi Access Point if both devices should communicate wirelessly